# How WSL sets path variable in ubuntu?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently WSL started to include NT path in ubuntu PATH variable. But I can't find *how* it does that? Where should I look?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: When I connect to ubuntu through SSH path is not set and I don't know where to get it. For now I just hardcoded it in .profile